# Graphic not showing on clickable interface

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, actionlistener

I have a program that should place an image of a coffee cup on the screen based on the button clicked by the user, however my image does not always show, and when it does, it does not move. Can someone please help me find where my code is incorrect? Thank you!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class MoveIt extends Applet implements ActionListener

{
    //Declare Variables
    private Image cup;
    private Panel keyPad;
    public int top = 15;
    public int left = 15;
    private boolean foundKey;

    public void init()
    {
        cup = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "cup.gif");

        Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();

        keyPad = new Panel();

        keysArray = new Button[5];


        //Create Buttons
        keysArray[0] = new Button("Up");
        keysArray[1] = new Button("Left");
        keysArray[2] = new Button("Right");
        keysArray[3] = new Button("Down");
        keysArray[4] = new Button("Center");

        keysArray[0].setActionCommand("Up");
        keysArray[1].setActionCommand("Left");
        keysArray[2].setActionCommand("Right");
        keysArray[3].setActionCommand("Down");
        keysArray[4].setActionCommand("Center");

        setBackground(Color.blue);

        //Sets the layout manager for the frame
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Sets the layout manager for the Panel
        keyPad.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Add Buttons to keypad panel
        keyPad.add(keysArray[0], BorderLayout.NORTH);
        keyPad.add(keysArray[1], BorderLayout.WEST);
        keyPad.add(keysArray[2], BorderLayout.EAST);
        keyPad.add(keysArray[3], BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        keyPad.add(keysArray[4], BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(myCanvas, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(keyPad, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //adds actionlistener to the buttons
        for(int i = 0; i < keysArray.length; i++)
           keysArray[i].addActionListener(this);
    }

    //puts image on the canvas
    public void paint( Graphics g )
    {
       g.drawImage( cup, left, top, this );
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String arg = e.getActionCommand();


        if(arg == "Up") top = top - 15;
        if(arg == "Left") left = left - 15;
        if(arg == "Right") left = left + 15;
        if(arg == "Down") top = top + 15;
        if(arg == "Center")
        {
            top = 60;
            left = 125;
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you call `paint()` at end instead of `repaint()`

Comment: If I call paint(), I get an error that method paint() cannot be found?

Comment: The image is supposed to be paint in `myCanvas`? Because your code try to paint the image inside the `MoveIt` drawing area.

Comment: If I'm understanding my information correctly, repaint() is supposed to repaint my canvas to apply the changes for the keypad buttons. My image isn't showing up at all...but I get no errors.

Comment: Thank you rendon...I moved repaint() outside of the MoveIt drawing area and at least now my graphic appears where the drawImage puts it. Now to figure out why the image isn't moving?...

Comment: Right now I'm formulating an answer, wait a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are so many problems with this, but lets start with the root cause....

This `if (arg == "Up") {` is not how `String` comparison works in Java.  Instead you should be using `"Up".equals(arg)` or if you don't care about the case `"Up".equalsIgnoreCase(arg)`

It is also highly unlikely that the user will be able to press more then one button at a time, so, instead of

```
if ("Up".equals(arg)) {...}
if ("Left".equals(arg)) {...}
```

You should use an `if-else` statement

```
if ("Up".equals(arg)) {
    //...
} else if ("Left".equals(arg)) {
    //..
} ...
```

**Updated**

Some of what I'm about to recommended has begin discussed by rendon, so +1 to him.

- (Personally) avoid AWT and use Swing instead.  AWT was replaced by Swing some 13+ years ago
- Avoid painting directly to top level containers.  There are a lot of layers that normally sit on top of these containers, which you can mess up by painting directly to them.  Instead, create a container (like a `JPanel` and build your application on top of it).  This will make it more portable and reusable in the future
- You MUST call `super.paintXxx` unless you have, very, very good reason not to and are prepared to deal with all the work that these methods do.
- Avoid "magic" numbers.  Instead rely on absolute values.  In this case, the width and height of the container you are painting to and the size of the image.  This will ensure that "center" is actually "center"

The following example demonstrates some of these ideas.  Basically, I've create a `ControlPane` pane which contains the buttons and the `CupPane`.  The `CupPane` is self contained and is responsible for painting and positioning the cup

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MoveIt extends JApplet {

    public void init() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new ControlPane());
    }

    public class CupPane extends JPanel {

        private Image cup;
        public int top = 15;
        public int left = 15;

        public CupPane() {
            cup = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "cup.png");
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(cup, left, top, this);
        }

        public void moveUp() {
            top -= 15;
            repaint();
        }

        public void moveLeft() {
            left -= 15;
            repaint();
        }

        public void moveRight() {
            left += 15;
            repaint();
        }

        public void moveDown() {
            top += 15;
            repaint();
        }

        public void center() {
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            top = (height - cup.getHeight(this)) / 2;
            left = (width - cup.getWidth(this)) / 2;
        }
    }

    public class ControlPane extends JPanel {

        private JPanel keyPad;
        public int top = 15;
        public int left = 15;
        private boolean foundKey;
        private JButton[] keysArray;
        private CupPane cupPane;

        public ControlPane() {
            keyPad = new JPanel();
            keysArray = new JButton[5];
            cupPane = new CupPane();

            //Create Buttons
            keysArray[0] = new JButton("Up");
            keysArray[1] = new JButton("Left");
            keysArray[2] = new JButton("Right");
            keysArray[3] = new JButton("Down");
            keysArray[4] = new JButton("Center");

            keysArray[0].setActionCommand("Up");
            keysArray[1].setActionCommand("Left");
            keysArray[2].setActionCommand("Right");
            keysArray[3].setActionCommand("Down");
            keysArray[4].setActionCommand("Center");

            setBackground(Color.blue);

            //Sets the layout manager for the frame
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            //Sets the layout manager for the Panel
            keyPad.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            //Add Buttons to keypad panel
            keyPad.add(keysArray[0], BorderLayout.NORTH);
            keyPad.add(keysArray[1], BorderLayout.WEST);
            keyPad.add(keysArray[2], BorderLayout.EAST);
            keyPad.add(keysArray[3], BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            keyPad.add(keysArray[4], BorderLayout.CENTER);

            add(cupPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(keyPad, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            ActionHandler handler = new ActionHandler();
            //adds actionlistener to the buttons
            for (int i = 0; i < keysArray.length; i++) {
                keysArray[i].addActionListener(handler);
            }

        }

        protected class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String arg = e.getActionCommand();

                if ("Up".equals(arg)) {
                    cupPane.moveUp();
                } else if ("Left".equals(arg)) {
                    cupPane.moveLeft();
                } else if ("Right".equals(arg)) {
                    cupPane.moveRight();
                } else if ("Down".equals(arg)) {
                    cupPane.moveDown();
                } else if ("Center".equals(arg)) {
                    cupPane.center();
                }
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find how to do the string argument. Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you have something like this:

```
______________________
|         ___        | 
|        |img|       | 
|                    | 
|____________________| 
|  <-     ^    ->    | 
|_________v__________|
```

I propose you to reorganize your approach.

1. Create a dedicated class for the drawing (e.g. `DrawingArea`).
2. Create a method for each action: `moveLeft()`, `moveRight()`,`moveUp()`, etc.
3. Then in the method `actionPerformed()`.

   ```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
     Button source = (Button)e.getSource();

     if(source == buttonUp)         // keysArray[0] in your case
       drawingArea.moveUp();
     else if(source == buttonLeft)  // keysArrays[1]
       drawingArea.moveLeft();
     else if(source == buttonRight) // keysArrays[2]
       drawingArea.moveRight();
     // etc.
   ```

   }
4. Create `DrawingArea` object in `MoveIt` and add it.

   ```
   DrawingArea drawingArea = new DrawingArea();
   add(drawingArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   ```

Comment: While some parts are a good suggestions, this won't solve the root cause of the OP's problem

Comment: I have not even realized about the string comparisons. :(

Comment: I'd also question the use of Applet

Comment: This is a prewritten program that I had to debug. I was able to get it to compile and run, just couldn't get this graphic figured out. I appreciate the help from both of you.

Comment: +1 for the separation of responsibility (and fixing the `String` comparison issue ;)) - Note, that you could have used a `switch` statement instead of an `if-else` statement if the OP is using Java 7 ;)

Comment: @SheilaMathews Then it's a bad example

Comment: I'm realizing that :-(